# unable to display correct date using strtotime

Tags: php

i'm having trouble to echo $newdate in 1995 12 02, the code below keep showing 1970/01/01. Would appreciate if anyone can assist here. Thanks alot.

```
<?php  
$month = "December";
$day = "02";
$year = "1995";
echo $newdate = date("Y/m/d",strtotime("$year $month $day"));
?>
```

Comment: You need to store it correctly(Proper format) : `strtotime("$day-$month-$year");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php  
$month = "December";
$day = "02";
$year = "1995";
echo $newdate = date("Y/m/d",strtotime("$day-$month-$year"));
?>
```

**Output:**

1995/12/02

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solutions

```
<?php  
$month = "December";
$day = "02";
$year = "1995";
$s=$month." ".$day." ".$year; 
echo $newdate = date("Y/m/d",strtotime($s));
?>
```

**Output**

> 1995/12/02